# Thumbnail Generation not working on server - PHP Gallery

Tags: php, centos, php-gd

This works perfectly fine on localhost but doesn't work on my server, could anyone tell me why? I've got php-gd (php-gd-5.1.6-32.el5.x86_64) on my Centos 5 box.

I have absolutely no idea why it wouldn't be working on the server so, if anyone has any ideas...

Here's the code;

```
    <?php

if (isset($_GET['img'])){
    // make thumbnail
    if(file_exists($_GET['img'])){
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(120);
        ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

        $src_size = getimagesize($_GET['img']);

        if($src_size === false){
            die('Thats not an image!');
        }

        $thumb_width    = 250;
        $thumb_height   = 200;

        if($src_size['mime'] === 'image/jpeg'){
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['img']);
        }else if($src_size['mime'] === 'image/png'){
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['img']);
        }else if($src_size['mime'] === 'image/gif'){
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($_GET['img']);
        }

        $src_aspect = round(($src_size[0] / $src_size[1]), 1);
        $thumb_aspect = round(($thumb_width / $thumb_height), 1);

        if($src_aspect < $thumb_aspect){
            //higher
            $new_size = array($thumb_width,($thumb_width / $src_size[0]) * $src_size[1]);
            $src_pos = array(0,(($new_size[1] - $thumb_height) * ($src_size[1] / $new_size[1])) / 2);
        }else if ($src_aspect > $thumb_aspect){
            //wider.
            $new_size = array(($thumb_width / $src_size[1]) * $src_size[0],$thumb_height);
            $src_pos = array(($new_size[0] - $thumb_width) / 2, 0);
        }else{
            // same shape
            $new_size = array($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
            $src_pos = array(0, 0);
        }

        if($new_size[0] < 1) $new_size[0] = 1;
        if($new_size[1] < 1) $new_size[0] = 1;

        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $src, 0, 0, $src_pos[0], $src_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $src_size[0], $src_size[1]);

        if($src_size['mime'] === 'image/jpeg'){
            imagejpeg($thumb, "thumbs/{$_GET['img']}");
        }else if($src_size['mime'] === 'image/png'){
            imagepng($thumb, "thumbs/{$_GET['img']}");
        }else if($src_size['mime'] === 'image/gif'){
            imagegif($thumb, "thumbs/{$_GET['img']}");
        }

        header("Location: thumbs/{$_GET['img']}");
    }   
    die();
}

if (is_dir('./thumbs') === false){
    mkdir('./thumbs', 0744);
}

$images = glob('*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <?php

            foreach($images as $image){
                if(file_exists("./thumbs/{$image}")){
                    echo "<a href=\"{$image}\" target=\"_blank\"><img style='border: 4px solid black;' src=\"thumbs/{$image}\" alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>";
                }else{
                    echo "<a href=\"{$image}\" target=\"_blank\"><img style='border: 4px solid black;' src=\"?img={$image}\" alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>";
                }
            }

            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you check the permissions on that directory?

Comment: Can you detail the error you receive when running the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure gd libraries are installed also on the server?

Comment: I think that it may have been that, I'm looking into it now.

Comment: :) ... so just becuase you are new to stackoverflow... i kindly ask you to accept the answer as the correct one... this will improve my reputation but also your's.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge I feel there could be few reasons for this.

1. GD library is not installed - You can find installation instruction from here. http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php
2. It could be a permission issue. You need write permission in particular directory to create thumbnail.
3. PHP execution not having sufficient memory. You can try with bellow code to set the memory limit manually. Put this at the beginning of the function. `ini_set('memory_limit', -1);` And reset it at the end of the function before return results. `ini_restore('memory_limit');`